# Movement of an object in a straight line towards a moving object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I have a 3d object that is moving towards another object - a target that changes direction along the y axis. The problem is that when the target changes direction, the 3d object starts moving in an arc. I want the object to move towards the target in a straight line.

I'm trying to adjust the speed of the object, the speed of the target, but even at high speed the object moves in a little arc.

I am using code:

```
object.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(object.position,
                new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z),
                Time.deltaTime * _objectSpeed);
object.up = target.position - object.position;
```

How can you make the object move in a clean, straight line when the target object moves?

Comment: Well yes. Because if it starts say on x -100 and is moving to zero. For each step it takes so -99 -98 etc. the chaser object takes a step to -100 thrn to -98 etc. the only thing you can do is argue that object is moving at a given speed and direction and predict where they will meet and take the direct route there. Much like shooting a moving target

Comment: Yes, something like shooting at a moving target. I set the speed of the object initially and the coordinates of the target are recalculated in the Update method. What might be needed for this?

Comment: I also thought about creating a guide, from the object to the target, that moves along with the target.